# How to check if facebook fanpage is liked

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

How do you check wether a facebook fanpage has been liked by the visitor. So I fill in my app_id, page_id in the code

This is the code I've got now

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'APP_ID',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    channelUrl : 'http://domain.com/tab/', // channel.html file
    oauth  : false // enable OAuth 2.0
  });

 (function($) {

  var session = FB.getSession();
      FB.api({
           method: 'fql.query',
           query: 'SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=PAGE_ID'
      },
   function(response) {
      if(response instanceof Array && response.length > 0)
          alert("YOU LIKE US!");
      else
          alert("YOU DON'T LIKE US YET!");
   });
 })(jQuery);
</script>
```

I get this error afterwards:

```
TypeError: FB.getSession is not a function
```

Answer (score 2):

If the current user has already liked your page or not, you can handle like this:

```
FB.api("me/likes/PAGE_ID", function(response) {
   if ( response.data.length == 1 ) { //there should be a single value inside `data` which is your page details
 
      alert('you like us :-)')
     } else {
        alert('please like our page')
 }});
```

Comment: you're going to need user_likes for this

Answer (score 0):

The FB.getSession method has been deprecated. Use `FB.getAuthResponse` instead.